# Showing Error while insertion of data in database, Drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms

I am new to drupal, and i am trying to insert data in database from form using Database API.
But its showing an error. That error is given below:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'x1' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO {members} (first_name, last_name, email, username, password, country) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => Ravneet [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => Singh [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => rvtsingh@gmail.com [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => rvtsingh [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 123456 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => India ) in form_test_form_submit() (line 63 of C:\wamp\www\Biding\sites\all\modules\own\form_test\form_test.module).
```

The code I used in module file to create code and insert in database is :

```
<?php
function form_test_menu() {
  $items['formtest'] = array(
    'title' => 'Sign up',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_test_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
  return $items;
}

function form_test_form($form, &$form_submit) {
  $form['firstname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Firstname'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['lastname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Lastname'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['email'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Email'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['username'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Username'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['password'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Password'),
    '#type' => 'password',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['country'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Country'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array('India' => 'India', 'Pakistan' => 'Pakistan', 'USA' => 'USA', 'UK' => 'UK', 'China' => 'China'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    );
  return $form;
}

function form_test_form_submit($form, $form_submit) {

  global $user;
    $user = db_insert('members')
    ->fields(array(
        'first_name' => $form_submit['values']['firstname'],
        'last_name' => $form_submit['values']['lastname'],
        'email' => $form_submit['values']['email'],
        'username' => $form_submit['values']['username'],
        'password' => $form_submit['values']['password'],
        'country' => $form_submit['values']['country'],
    ))
    ->execute();

    drupal_set_message("You have registered successfully.");

}
```

Please help me to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is related to your mysql table `member` structure. The member table field `x1` doesn't have a default value that means you need to serve a value on every insert,  you can solve this in three ways,

1. Pass the value in the field array Ex: `'x1' => "<value here>",`
2. Add a default value / NULL (based on your requirement) through altering your table

> (ALTER TABLE `member` CHANGE `x1` `x1` NOT NULL DEFAULT '') OR (ALTER TABLE `member` CHANGE `x1` `x1` NULL)

3.Check your table mode, if the table mode is STRICT change it to `SET GLOBAL sql_mode='';` [REFERENCE : SQL Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html)